# Solve the equation $ 5^{2x}-17\cdot 5{^x}+60=0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I recently bought the textbook titled Mathematical Methods Queensland, Australia, Units $3\&4$. In Chapter $1$, Question $5c$, the following question is asked:

> Find the solutions to
> $$
> 5^{2x}-17\cdot 5{^x}+60=0
> $$

The solution key states $$x=\log_5(12)\text{ or }x=1$$

I do not understand how they arrived to this solution and I am unable to attack or answer the question myself.

Comment: Hint: set $t=5^x$. What does the equation look like now, in terms of $t$?

Comment: Your title and wording are not exact: the subject is not to inverse a function but to solve an equation.

Comment: @AnneBauval when I glanced at title , I thought "wow! something interesting" But it was just quadratic equations. Haha

Comment: $5^{2x}-17\cdot 5{^x}+60=0$ is not a function, it's an equation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with slightly non-standard way of solving this.

Starting with
$$ 5^{2x}-16\cdot 5^{x}+60=0$$

Calculating inverse directly from a polynomial is quite complicated for the following reasons:
$$ x \rightarrow (x,x) \rightarrow (x_0,x_1) $$

And then rewriting the equation to:
$$ f(x_0,y_0)=5^{2x_0} - 17\cdot 5^{x_1} +60=0$$

Moving $60$ and $-17 \cdot 5^{x_1}$ to other side we get:

$$ 5^{2x_0} = 17\cdot 5^{x_1}-60 $$

This is of form $f_0(x_0)=f_1(x_1)$ where $f_0(x_0)=5^{2x_0}$ and $f_1(x_1)=17 \cdot 5^{x_1}-60$.

Thus we have pullback:
$$ \{ (x_0,x_1) | f_0(x_0)=f_1(x_1) \}$$

Thus there's an arrow: $t::(x \rightarrow (x,x) \rightarrow (x_0,x_1))$ such that $f_0\circ \pi_1 \circ t = f_1 \circ \pi_2 \circ t=k$. There should be arrow intersection/pullback diagram commutes in $x\rightarrow {im}(k)$, but since you wanted inverse solution, I'll go slightly different route:

in ${im}(k)$, we have an infinite diagonal equality matrix in $R$: $\{y_0=y_1 |(y_0,y_1)\in R \times R\}$ where $y_0=f_0 \circ \pi_1 \circ t$ and $y_1=f_1 \circ \pi_2 \circ t$.

Now inverse of $y_0$ and $y_1$ are:
$$ y_0^{-1} = t^{-1} \circ (x_0,-) \circ f_0^{-1} $$ and
$$ y_1^{-1} = t^{-1} \circ (-,x_1) \circ f_1^{-1} $$.

So now we just need to know the inverse of $f_0$ and $f_1$ to solve the problem:
$$f_0^{-1}(y_0) = log_5(\frac{y_0}{2}) = x_0$$ and
$$f_1^{-1}(y_1) = log_5(\frac{y_1+60}{17}) = x_1$$

Then the remaining problem is to go forwards the inverse arrows from diagonal $(y_0,y_1)$ to find $(x_0,x_1)$ and then filter out solutions where $x_0\neq x_1$ to get values for x. QED.